# JSON string to HTML

Tags: json

in my JSON string (from the server response) I have a HTML tags, eg `abc<br/>dd`. That string goes to the DOM element as its content.

How to display it as a proper HTML, instead of raw string ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set it as the HTML rather than the text. Using DOM directly, you'd set `element.innerHTML = myValue;`. If you're using jQuery, you'd use `$('#myElement').html(myValue);`.